# How to deploy react and django in aws with a ssl and a domain

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, ssl

Currently, I deployed react (port 80 & 443) and django (port 8000) in aws ec2 server.
I bought a domain and standard ssl cert. It sets up in react (443).

In the server connection of react, it is using axios and connect to domain:8000 but I think it's not a good solution. Safari cannot connect to this kind of connection.
Therefore, I add a subdomain: api.domain and change the connection from domain:8000 to api.domain. Since I don't have wildcard ssl cert, so https blocks my api.domain connection in the server.

What is the best practice of this case?

Comment: you can try using a load balancer and run load balancer on port 80 and forward the traffic to port 8000. you can also try using ACM for free certificates with in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, fixed by using nginx to route the internal ports to external ports